# NAudio WaveOut.Init takes a very long time (sometimes)

Tags: naudio

I've been using NAudio recently and for the most part I'm very happy with the library. However, I've been experiencing a very annoying intermittent issue that causes the `Init` method to take a very long time to execute (over 30 seconds).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        var waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 2);
        _wavePlayer = new WaveOutEvent();
        _mixingSampleProvider = new MixingSampleProvider(waveFormat)
        {
            ReadFully = true
        };
        _wavePlayer.Init(_mixingSampleProvider); // program halts here
        _wavePlayer.Play();
```

I've also tried using `WaveOut` instead of `WaveOutEvent` and I get the same problem.

I can reproduce this issue about 1 in every 3 times or so. So it's not completely easy to reproduce but it's often enough to be very, very annoying.

Comment: what soundcard are you using?

Comment: The problem usually occurs on an old HP laptop. Device manager says it's an Intel(R) Display Audio. Also there's a IDT High Definition Audio CODEC in there. I can't say for certain if I've seen the issue on my desktop machine. I'll keep an eye on it. Is it worth trying one of the other IWavePlayer's? If so which would you recommend?

Comment: It is quite strange. Try upgrading the drivers. DirectSoundOut might be worth a try instead.

Comment: As far as I can tell DirectSoundOut works around the problem. Unfortunately it's still not clear why WaveOut plays up. Can you think of any reason why I shouldn't use DirectSoundOut over WaveOut?  If you add the workaround as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks Mark.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea why WaveOut should hang but not DirectSoundOut. I mainly use WaveOut / WaveOutEvent myself and have never come across this issue before.